# How to pass extra parameter in jquery post request from outside click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i have jquery request like below ,

```
$('#filterForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataString = $('#filterForm').serialize();
        var class2011 = document.getElementById("2011").className;
        //var validate = validateFilter();
        alert(dataString);
        if(class2011=='yearOn')
            {
                dataString+='&year=2011';
                document.getElementById("2011").className='yearOff';
            }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById("2011").className='yearOn';
            }

         alert (dataString);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myServlet",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                /*var a = data;
                alert(data);*/
            }
          });
```

and my Form is like ,

```
<form  method="post" name="filterForm" id="filterForm">
  <!-- some input elements -->
</form>
```

Well, I am triggering jquery submit on submit event of a form ,(it's working fine) 
I want pass one extra parameter inside form  which is not in above form content but it's outside in page
it's like below

[Check this image link for code preview][1]

So how can i trigger above event , on click of , element with class yearOn ( check above html snippet )  and class yearOff ,  with additional  parameter of year set to either 2011 or 2010

Comment: The code looks good offhand. What is the result of the alert of your datastring after appending the year= parameter?

Comment: there is no problem with result , but i want to call same function with additional one parameter in same post request ,  but how can i call the same post request on click of some outside div or anchor element with "additional paramter" in the request , can i modify submit event ,and add one additional parameter in submit(function(e, extra para )  ?

Comment: You shouldn't use a string for `data` ever. Create an object instead; this makes both accessing values easier and saves you from having to care about escaping characters such as `&` inside the values.

Comment: If you are unsure how to or don't understand "Create an object" it simple means: data: { id = value } where id is the name of the parameter on your action and value is the value you are passing

Comment: i guess, i can do this with hidden element inside form , is there any better way to do the same ?

Comment: k.. u can use hidden filed. but mension attribut name="year" .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#filterForm').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var dataString = $('#filterForm').serialize();
                if ($("#2011").hasClass('yearOn')) {
                    dataString += '&year=2011';
                    $("#2011").removeClass('yearOn').addClass('yearOff');
                }
                else {
                    $("#2011").removeClass('yearOff').addClass('yearOn'); 
                }

                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "/myServlet",
                    type: "POST",                       
                    data: dataString,
                    success: function (data) {
                        /*var a = data;
                        alert(data);*/
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) If you are using jQuery already, you can use the $.post() function provided by jquery. It will make your life easier in most cases.

2.) I have always had a successful post with extra parameters this way:

**Build you extra parameters here**

```
    commands={
            year:'2011'
    };
```

**Combine it with your form serialize**

```
var dataString=$.param(commands)+'&'+$("#filterForm").serialize();
```

**Perform your post here**

```
$.post("myServlet",data,
        function(data) {
            /*var a = data;
        alert(data);*/
    }
    );
```

**OR use $.ajax if you really love it**

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "myServlet",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            /*var a = data;
            alert(data);*/
      }
```

---

**In the end, here is the full code the way you are doing it now**

```
   $('#filterForm').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var class2011 = document.getElementById("2011").className;
        //var validate = validateFilter();
        alert(dataString);
        if(class2011=='yearOn') {
                dataString+='&year=2011';
                document.getElementById("2011").className='yearOff';
        } else {
            document.getElementById("2011").className='yearOn';
        }
         commands={
                year:'2011'
         };

         var dataString=$.param(commands)+'&'+$("#filterForm").serialize();

         alert (dataString);

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myServlet",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data) {
                /*var a = data;
                alert(data);*/
          }
    });
```